# c# SQL to List error

Tags: c#

real newbie question and I would appreciate any support you could offer.
I am trying to output SQL results to a list. But when I return the list I get 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
This my code, any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
    public static List<string> GetDTSXPackages()
    {
        List<String> packages = new List<String>();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString()))
        {
            string query = "SELECT PackageName FROM SharedServices.DTSXPackages";
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        packages.Add(reader["PackageName"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return packages;
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> x = SQLAccessLayer.GetDTSXPackages();

        foreach (var package in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code seems ok. How do you call GetDTSXPackages and use the returned value?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this list? I guess, you're trying to write it to console or something like this, using `List.ToString` since output you've provided is exactly result of calling `ToString` on such a list.

Comment: I suppose you are expecting `packages.ToString()` to display `[package1,package2]` ? Iterate over the list

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error
By doing a loop you can see all values

```
foreach(var i in Packages)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: @user3801561 its same code..instead of printing the each var u r printing wrongly..thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

To

```
Console.WriteLine(package);
```

Comment: @user3801561 Glad I could help